# How to pass from detail view to form foreignkey field?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a detail view of car and btn of booking href to booking form . I want to pass that car which detail is showing. Rather than i always select from foreignkey dropdown car select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in car detail view put:

```
<a href="{% url 'car_booking' %}?car={{ car.id }}">Booking Now</a>
```

then in view of car booking:

```
class BookingView(FormView):
    template_name = 'car/booking.html'
    form_class = BookingForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!
        try:
            kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', '')) 
        except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
            kwargs['car'] = None
        return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # if you still want to keep select car in form,and auto select this car do as:
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(BookingView, self).get_initial()
        if 'car' in self.request.GET:
            try:
                initial['book_car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['car'])
            except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
                pass     
        return initial
```

url may like:

```
path('booking/', BookingView.as_view(), name='car_booking'),
```

Comment: **what will be my url path in urls.py file ?** for booking

Comment: **NameError: name 'BookingView' is not defined** _ERROR_

Comment: it's view.BookingView.as_view()

Comment: **see in my answer the image i attached** @ykh

Comment: same as you gave me

Comment: the code I want you to post is forms.py not views.py

Comment: you don't copy get_initial in views

Comment: i copied and run it was no effect of it then i removed n see still the same

Comment: change initial['car'] to initial['book_car'] in get_initial

Comment: after changing that in initial . nothing happened it was same as it is

Comment: <a href="{% url 'buggy_app:car_booking' %}?car={{car_detail.id }}">Booking Now</a>

Comment: you should change the code by your situation.Instead of waiting for someone to change it for you

Comment: sorry i am beginner its my first app

Comment: still it doesnt grabbing the key